# Get the count from activesheet NOT from previous active sheet

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

This code supposed to sort column B based on duplicates and paste the duplicates to newly created sheet. and then I would like to run same code to process active sheet (Sheet4) and move duplicates to sheet5.

```
lr = Cells.Find("*", After:=[a1], searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

lr is getting me count from previous sheet(Sheet1). How to make sure the lr count is from new sheet4 and it always gets the count from active sheet?

```
Sub duplicate()
Dim t As Single
t = Timer
Dim d As Object, x&, xcol As String
Dim lc&, lr&, k(), e As Range
Dim oWS1, oWS2 As Worksheet
xcol = "B"
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
Worksheets(sheetname).Activate

lc = Cells.Find("*", After:=[a1], searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
lr = Cells.Find("*", After:=[a1], searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
ReDim k(1 To lr, 1 To 1)
Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each e In Cells(1, xcol).Resize(lr)
    If Not d.exists(e.Value) Then
        d(e.Value) = 1
        k(e.Row, 1) = 1
    End If
Next e
If d.Count = lr Then
    MsgBox "No duplicates"
    Exit Sub
End If

Cells(1, lc + 1).Resize(lr) = k
Range("A1", Cells(lr, lc + 1)).Sort Cells(1, lc + 1), 1
x = Cells(1, lc + 1).End(4).Row
Set tgt = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
tgtLastRow = tgt.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Cells(x + 1, 1).Resize(lr - x, lc).Copy tgt.Range("A" & tgtLastRow)
Cells(x + 1, 1).Resize(lr - x, lc).Clear
Cells(1, lc + 1).Resize(x).Clear
MsgBox "Code took " & Format(Timer - t, "0.00 secs")
MsgBox lr & " rows" & vbLf & lc & " columns" & vbLf & _
    lr - x & " duplicate rows"
End Sub
```

Comment: You must have sheet1 selected when you set sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found a much simpler method for you. If sheet4 is what you want the count from then simply alter your code to be:

```
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name

lc = Cells.Find("*", After:=[a1], searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
lr = Cells.Find("*", After:=[a1], searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

This will count the rows of the activesheet:

```
With ActiveSheet

Application.StatusBar = "Counting Rows" 'this just lets your user know what is happening
'you don't have to include this

Count1 = Application.CountA(Range("A:A")) 'if row A would give an accurate count

End With
```

There are MANY methods to get the count. If this one is not what you want, please comment and I'll suggest another.